# Only root can open a "fstab" entry

Tags: fstab, nas

I created an entry in my `/etc/fstab` file:

```
//192.168.178.1/fritzbox-nas/ /media/usbplatte cifs credentials=/home/palomar/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

and I thought it worked because it appeared in the file manager (Nautilus) but when I clicked on it, it said that only the user `root` can do that. Is there a way to change that?

I have already watched through multiple forum posts but nobody else seems to have this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want non-root users to be able to mount a record of `/etc/fstab`, simply add the `user` option to the respective line of `/etc/fstab`.

As you have used an option (`credentials`) already, use comma (without spaces) to separate multiple options. I’d prefer to put `user` as the first option, so it cannot be overlooked at the end of the path: `user,credentials=/home/palomar/.smbcredentials`

The whole resulting line (I don’t guarantee that other fields are correct):

```
//192.168.178.1/fritzbox-nas/ /media/usbplatte cifs user,credentials=/home/palomar/.smbcredentials 0 0
```

To apply the change, use the command `sudo mount -a` (or reboot the machine).

See also:
[`man fstab`](https://linux.die.net/man/5/fstab),
[`man mount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

Comment: OP pls don't forget to the above mentioned command!!!